# Resolving One jQuery Promise Within Another Using $.when & $.then

Tags: jquery

Trying to resolve one promise within another but I am getting the error `Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded`

```
$.when(ajaxCallOne()).then(function(data) {
    if (data === "yes") {           
       $.when(ajaxCallTwo()).then(function(data2) {
          console.log(data2);
       }, function(){ });
    }
}, function(){  });
```

UPDATE

ajaxCallOne() and ajaxCallTwo() are actually called 
from a generic function using different parameters.

```
function ajaxCall(rUrl, rMethod, rData) {
    return $.ajax({
        url: rUrl,
        method: rMethod,
        data: rData
    });
}


$.when(ajaxCall(url1, method1, data1)).then(function(data) {
    if (data === "yes") {           
       $.when(ajaxCall(url2, method2, data2)).then(function(data2) {
          console.log(data2);
       }, function(){ });
    }
}, function(){  });
```

data1 and data2 are javascript Objects

Comment: The error implies you're creating an infinite loop. Does `ajaxCallOne()` call `ajaxCallTwo()`? Also, just to improve your code, don't use `yes` as a string; use a boolean value properly. Secondly, you don't *have* to provide the callback function. If they're empty, remove them.

Comment: Show us the body of function`ajaxCallOne()` and `ajaxCallTwo()` please, because I suspect that you're trying to pass a jquery object as parameter (I think it can also cause this type of error)

Comment: Updated. Yes a jQuery object is being passed as a parameter

Comment: @Shane Show us what are you passing to `rData` parameter, because in your example you don't pass any parameters at all to those functions

Comment: @Alon Eitan rData is a javascript object

Comment: Just wonder why do you use `$.when` with single promise?

Comment: Make sure your `data1` and `data2` do not contain circular references. Check if you could do `console.log($.param(data1), $.param(data2))`

Comment: There's no infinite recursion in that code, therefore "Maximum call stack size exceeded" must be caused by something else - something you've not revealed.